# How to CompleteCheckoutSession for PHP Amazon Pay SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-pay

I've follow the instruction how to integrate Amazon V2 for PHP

```
https://github.com/amzn/amazon-pay-api-sdk-php
```

But I could not find any section how can I implement the Complete Checkout Session function in order to get "chargeID".

Here is what I've implement

```
$payload = array(
    'webCheckoutDetails' => array(
    "checkoutResultReturnUrl" => HTTPS_SERVER . "index.php?route=payment/amazon/returnURL"
),
'paymentDetails' => array(
    'paymentIntent' => 'Authorize',
    'canHandlePendingAuthorization' => false,
    'chargeAmount' => array(
        'amount' => (int)$total_amount,
        'currencyCode' => 'JPY'
    ),
),
'merchantMetadata' => array(
    'merchantReferenceId' => $order_id,
    'merchantStoreName' => 'MWYW Online Store',
    'noteToBuyer' => 'Thank you for your order!'
)
);

try {

$client = new Amazon\Pay\API\Client($amazonpay_config);
$result = $client->updateCheckoutSession($checkoutSessionId, $payload);



$payload = array(
    'chargeAmount' => array(
            'amount' => (int)$total_amount,
            'currencyCode' => 'JPY'
        ),
);

$result = $client->completeCheckoutSession($checkoutSessionId, $payload);
```

But I got the error message like this

{"reasonCode":"InvalidCheckoutSessionStatus","message":"You tried to call an operation on a Checkout Session that is in a state where that operation is not allowed"}

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Checkout Session response will include a Constraint object until all mandatory parameters have been provided. (mandatory parameters: checkoutResultReturnUrl, chargeAmount, paymentIntent)

Once there are no constraints, the response will return a unique **amazonPayRedirectUrl**. Redirect the buyer to that URL to have Amazon Pay run the transaction. Then the buyer will be redirected to **checkoutResultReturnUrl** after Amazon Pay has processed the transaction (including any decline flows if necessary). The Amazon Pay checkout session ID will be included as a query parameter on checkoutResultReturnUrl.

Comment: Excuse me, so what I missed on updateCheckoutSession() ?

Comment: The workflow should be UpdateCheckoutSession -> check response for errors -> if no errors, redirect to amazonPayRedirectUrl (returned in updateCheckoutSession response) -> on checkoutResultReturnUrl page call getCheckoutSession to check for errors -> if no errors, call completeCheckoutSession.  

Based on the code you shared, you're calling completeCheckoutSession immediately after updateCheckoutSession.  As you can see, there's a few more necessary steps, and the redirect to amazonPayRedirectUrl MUST happen -prior- to calling completeCheckoutSession.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The result of `::updateCheckoutSession()` will give you a `amazonPayRedirectUrl` in `webCheckoutDetails`. You need to redirect the client to this URL.

After the client has finished their input on that external page they will be redirected back to your `checkoutResultReturnUrl`. At this point you will be able to complete the CheckoutSession.

Comment: Excuse me , where can I set the amazonPayRedirectUrl value? Now I got NULL from updateCheckoutSession()

Comment: I've used this code to generate button

Comment: $client = new Amazon\Pay\API\Client($amazonpay_config);
  $payload = '{"storeId":"'. $store_id .'","webCheckoutDetails":{"checkoutReviewReturnUrl":"'. $return_url .'"}}';


$signature = $client->generateButtonSignature($payload);

Comment: @ChhornSoro The amazonPayRedirectUrl is not a URL you set. It is returned by the API and should be part of `$result` after your line `$result = $client->updateCheckoutSession($checkoutSessionId, $payload);`, if there are no constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = array('x-amz-pay-Idempotency-Key' => uniqid()); // added externally

$client = new Amazon\Pay\API\Client($amazonpay_config);
$result = $client->updateCheckoutSession($checkoutSessionId, $payload , $headers);
```

This Worked for me for getting the web checkout details  data in $response

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).